# is there any solution for this setupWithViewPager error?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

Ive been troubleshooting this since last night, I used the viewpager2 becuase the original viewpager inside androidstudio is missing. I don't know whats causing the error, can you guys help me?

````
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(firebaseUser.getUid());

        myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                Users users = snapshot.getValue(Users.class);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
        //TabLayout and viewpager
        TableLayout tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);

        ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(new ChatFragment(), "chats" ); // this line can crash
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(new UsersFragment(), "Users" ); // this line can crash

        viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);

        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    }```
````

Answer (score 0):

From [Refactor TabLayout interfaces](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/vp2-migration#tablayout):

> Finally, you must update the code that attaches the TabLayout object
> to the ViewPager object. While TabLayout uses its own
> setupWithViewPager() method to integrate with ViewPager, it requires a
> TabLayoutMediator instance to integrate with ViewPager2.

To work with ViewPager2, you cannot use `setupWithViewPager` method anymore, you must use TabLayoutMediator instead.

```
// TODO: Comment-out or remove this line
// tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

new TabLayoutMediator(tabLayout, viewPager, new TabLayoutMediator.TabConfigurationStrategy() {
    @Override
    public void onConfigureTab(@NonNull TabLayout.Tab tab, int position) {
        String tabTitle = "";
        if (position == 0) {
            tabTitle = "chats";
        } else if (position == 1) {
            tabTitle = "Users";
        }
        tab.setText(tabTitle);
    }
}).attach();
```

Also, you should ***never pass actual Fragment instances to a FragmentPagerAdapter***. You should **always create a new instance** of the Fragment inside `getItem()` (in the case of FragmentPagerAdapter/FragmentStatePagerAdapter) and also inside `createFragment()` (in the case of `FragmentStateAdapter`).